# Elastic search query to return the version of kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am running on kibana 5.4.0
I wanted to know if there is an Elastic search GET api query that I can run against the .kibana index which returns the version of kibana I am running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why query elasticsearch? Kibana itself offers that capabiltity:

```
cinhtau@omega:~> curl -v localhost:5601/status
* About to connect() to localhost port 5601 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5601 (#0)
> GET /status HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:5601
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< location: https://localhost:5601/status
< kbn-name: kibana
< kbn-version: 5.6.1
< kbn-xpack-sig: 83f97b6a01fc027688f430e60e935b27
< cache-control: no-cache
< content-length: 0
< Date: Fri, 22 Sep 2017 08:51:43 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

From the response header you can see it is *5.6.1*. There is a way to query it from Elasticsearch, but IMHO doesn't make sense to ask Elasticsearch, information about Kibana.